# In Jenkins I received the error: Could not find the default SASS implementation

Tags: jenkins, ember.js, ember-cli

In Jenkins we recently started getting the following error:

```
Could not find the default SASS implementation. Run the default blueprint:
   ember g ember-cli-sass
Or install an implementation such as "node-sass" and add an implementation option. For example:
   sassOptions: {implementation: require("node-sass")}
```

This started out of the blue without any changes to the app.

I added the `sassOptions` and installed `ember-cli-sass` and it fixed the issue on my local machine, but the app is build in a docker container and I am unsure how to run the command `ember g ember-cli-sass`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

```
let app = new EmberAddon(defaults, {
  sassOptions: { implementation: require("node-sass") },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ola @Ivan  thank you for your question!

So you say that you are running Ember inside a docker container? that is likely the cause of some of your issues.

Firstly the only way that this could "[start] out of the blue without any changes to the app." is if your dependencies are floating. If you updated ember-cli-sass manually this would have caused the problem but I wonder do you have a package-lock.json in your project (or a yarn.lock)?

What running `ember g ember-cli-sass` actually does it is makes sure that your package.json has a valid SASS implementation and configures it correctly for you.

You can install ember-cli (to get the `ember` command) globally on your machine and it won't affect your docker container in any way. You can do this by running `npm i -g ember-cli`. Then you can run `ember g ember-cli-sass` and when you restart the app it should start working